# To create document fragment to avoid flickring jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When ever i sent a request to the server, I am need to update a very long content. Now what I am doing here once I get response from server I am just replacing the new content in my in parent wrapper Id, which show some flickring effects.

```
success:function(response) {

          $("#wrapper").html(response.newHtml);
        },
```

Now here i am thinking to load the content using document fragment and to replace with old one.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Hi, can you please show it in jsfiddle.net?

Comment: See detach http://api.jquery.com/detach/ to remove your #wrapper from the dom, then insert the html in it and put it back in its place. It helps when adding a lot of data to do it "in the back".